# How to modify browser proxy settings adobe air?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

Is it possible to modify browser proxy settings with flex/actionscript/air?

Thanks in advance!
Joseph

Answer (score 0):

As far as Flash Player runs in sandbox and hasn't any access to native environment it is impossible to reach your goal with Flex/Flash web application.

Using Adobe AIR you can create native utilities to change proxy settings and/or set corresponding browser extensions [using NativeProcess](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) and [native installers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS789ea67d3e73a8b22388411123785d839c-8000.html).